# variable variables in sh or dash

Tags: unix, sh, dash-shell

The following code executes fine on `bash`.

```
sms="SMSFile"
email="EmailSubj"
for x in sms email; do echo variable \$$x=${!x}; done;
```

Output is

```
variable $sms=SMSFile
variable $email=EmailSubj
```

But I need to write it in `sh` NOT `bash`. if I execute same command in `sh` it gives me error

```
sh: 3: Bad substitution
```

This is due to `${!x}`. I looked up the manual of `sh` which does not state anything about such parameter expansion.  So `sh` does not support it I believe. If not how can use variable variables in `sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you have any option but to use `eval`.

The following:

```
sms="SMSFile"
email="EmailSubj"
for x in sms email; do eval val=\$$x; echo variable \$$x=$val; done;
```

should result in:

```
variable $sms=SMSFile
variable $email=EmailSubj
```

in both `sh` and `dash`.